# Having trouble getting curl to work properly. Is there something I am not understanding?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to go through a basic curl example. I have a php file running on a server that seems to have curl properly installed and I have another empty text document on the server that I am trying to have information copied to. When I run the script by opening the php file, no information is written to the text file.

For the server, it says curl is enabled:

```
curl
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
```

Here is the php file I am trying to run:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I have an empty file named "example_homepage.txt" in the same folder. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: It's fine to get down-votes for a poor question, but it would be helpful to get some constructive feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is working perfectly. A quick test with `curl example.com` shows that it returns no output. If you want to actually fetch content, try a **real site** like `$ch = curl_init("http://www.google.com/");`.

The address "www.example.com" is just that, an example. You're meant to replace it with something real.

Comment: haha, well maybe it was a dumb question, but it's nice when the problem is fixed so quickly

Comment: Actually example.com has a redirect. So you can still use it to get content, but you need to tell cURL to follow redirects.

Comment: @Eli ok Ill check that out. Thanks for letting me know. I did check example.com and it led me to a webpage but I didn't notice it was a redirect at the time or that that was a problem.